Can anyone explain why func3 and func4 do not conform to the protocol?
This does not compile in Swift 5.10.
protocol Common {
  func func1() -> Common
  func func2() -> Common
  func func3() -> Common
  func func4() -> Common
}

struct Model: Common {
  func func1() -> any Common {self}
  func func2() -> Common     {self}
  func func3() -> Self       {self}    // Not conformant
  func func4() -> Model      {self}    // Not conformant   
}


It's not clear to me why Self and Model don't conform to the Common protocol. I would not have thought to add "any" either, but that's what Xcode's "fix" generates.

func func3() -> Common

This is exactly equivalent to:
func func3() -> any Common

(For historical reasons, the any is assumed in Swift 5.) This means that func1() returns an existential that contains a type conforming to Common. Existential are not free. They are real structures in memory, and change the layout of data.
func func3() -> Self 

This does not return an existential container. It returns an actual value which will have a different memory layout. In order for this to conform, the compiler would need to inject extra code of the form:
// In the worst case, this will require a heap allocation and copy.
func func3() -> any Common { return func3() as any Common }

I haven't tested it, but I don't expect the above code to actually work correctly since its ambiguous. But the compiler would need to write something "like" this to insert the existential container. This is similar to the fact that this does not work:
protocol Common {
    func func1() -> Int?
}

// Does not conform
struct Model: Common {
    func func1() -> Int { 1 }
}

Again, there's no fundamental reason that a method that returns Int can't stand-in for a method that returns Int?, but it would have performance impact, and the compiler does not do it.
On the other hand, it does support non-async methods for async methods:
protocol Common {
    func func1() async -> Int
}

// This is fine
struct Model: Common {
    func func1() -> Int { 1 }
}

It also supports automatically bridging non-throwing methods to throwing methods. I don't believe there's any memory layout impact here, so there's no cost (I believe) to supporting this conversion.
But for other things, there is, and it's not automatically supported.

A protocol describes exactly what an adopter must say. func func3() -> Common means an adopter must literally declare
func func3() -> Common {

in order to be conformant. It doesn't matter what you think Self or Model would mean; the protocol has dictated the actual expression that must appear in the would-be adopter.

I don't think it's always exact. If you have -> Self in a protocol requirement, you can satisfy it with the concrete type name instead (except for non-final classes)

@Alexander The word Self has a special meaning in that situation: it is a blank for "The Type Of The Adopter". I don't think it was an especially good linguistic choice as the word with that meaning, but we're stuck with it now.

Yeah I understand that, but it's still a case where a implementation's type isn't spelled verbatim the same as the protocol requirement it satisfies

I think the others have answered the question as to why the implementations of func3 and func4 are warning you that they do not conform to the protocol. (+1)
My question is the protocol’s intent: Specifically, are these protocol functions are really intended to say that func1-4 in a particular Common type can really return any Common type (including different types that also happen to conform to Common)? Or, is the intent that these functions should only return an instance of that particular Common type?
If the latter was intended, I might suggest defining the protocol to say that func5-6 will not return any random Common type, but rather only an instance of Self.
For example:
protocol Common {
    func func5() -> Self
    func func6() -> Self
}

struct Model: Common {
    func func5() -> Self       { self }      // OK
    func func6() -> Model      { self }      // OK
}

struct Model2: Common {
    func func5() -> Common     { self }      // As intended: compiler complains that method signature was expecting a return type this specific type, not `any Common`; note, it doesn’t matter that this happens to return an instance of the correct type, namely `Self`, but rather that the function signature does not match the protocol precisely
    func func6() -> Model      { Model() }   // As intended: compiler complains that it is returning a different `Common` type
}

If your intent that these functions should only return the particular type in which the method was defined (not just any random Common type), using Self in the protocol definition will make this explicit.
